# how to convert a character to an integer in C++?

Tags: c++

How to convert a character to an integer in C++??

I want to input integers from user and stop the input as soon as the user enters a *.
I am using the following code:

```
while(true) {
  cin >> x;
  if (x == (int) '*')
    break;
}
```

where I am explicitily typecasting * into an int. But this doesnt seem to work.

I also tried

```
while(true) {
  cin >> x;
  if (x == (int) '*' - '0')
    break;
}
```

But it didn't help much.What else can I do?? 
x indeed is an integer.
But i want to input an integer from the user. Only when the user enters * I want to go out of loop.
Should I declare x as char and then convert it into int and use it?
Cant i convert the char to an int?

Comment: what is the output of `cout << x;` if you typed in a *?

Comment: Show the declaration of variable 'x'.

Comment: x is an int.
int x;
The statement cout << x hangs the program...

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like this, where you grab a string. check if its your "end of input" string, and then convert the string to an int if it isn't.

Its still missing a bunch of error checks though.

```
while(true) {
  std::string s
  cin >> s;
  if (s == "*" ) break;
  std::stringstrem ss(s);
  ss>>x;
}
```

Comment: The point is that s needs to be an int.
I have to input an int as i use it later in my algo..

Comment: In this case x is still an int. You're just reading the string into chunks then testing each chunk to see if its "*", then converting it to an int and storing it in x if it is not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtol` to convert a string to integer :

http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol

Comment: If `x` is defined as `int` then the OPs code will do the same thing.

Comment: Not if you want to detect the first non digit character :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you already use `std`, you should read strings and use `std::string` for comparison.
Look into it.

I'm not going to give you a full solution as I think you'd be better off investigation this on your own, now that you know where to look.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have defined `x` as an `int`; try defining it as `char`:

```
char x;
while (true)
{
    cin >> x;
    if (x == '*')
        break;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use atoi() to get the char converted to int.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure you can't capture a character into an integer.  Instead, capture a char, check for *, then pseudo-convert it to an integer.

```
char c;
while(true) {
   cin >> c;
   if (c == '*')
      break;
   int x = c - '0';
   if(x >= 0 && x <= 9){
      //do something with integer x
   }
}
```

However, this will only handle single digit integers between 0 and 9.